# How to do Spotify Api Post Request using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I'm trying to add a song to the playback queue using [this](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/) endpoint:

```
   const add = async () => {
   

    try {
      
      const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=${songUrl}&device_id=${deviceId}`
     
      await axios.patch(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${to}`
        },
    })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
   
   
}
```

I'm getting a status 401 error with a message that says no token provided. But when I console.log the token it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with the Spotify API yet, however, according to [their docs](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/), you need to send a POST request, not a PATCH, which is what you used.

Use `axios.post()` instead of `axios.patch()`:

```js
const add = async (songUrl, deviceId, token) => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=${songUrl}&device_id=${deviceId}`;

    await axios.post(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought that would solve the problem but it still showing AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401'. I was able to add the song to queue using the spotify api website but not my own post request. I also tried Arko's suggestion to add the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The second param of your post request should be `body` and the third param should be `headers`. Also, you haven't added all the headers as mentioned in the documentation.

```
headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + newAccessToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

Get your access token from here: https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/

If it still doesn't work try the curl method as mentioned in their docs and if it works, switch it to axios.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as you, what I realised was I was passing the header as data rather than as config. This code below should work for you as it works for me.

```
const add = async () => {
  try { 
    const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=${songUrl}&device_id=${deviceId}`
    await axios.post(url, null,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${to}`
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```